# Does "C follows A" apply to "ABCDE"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Given the sequence:

> ABCDE

I think it makes sense to say "B follows A", but what about "C follows A"? I mean, is "follow" limited to the case where something comes *right* after something else? Does it imply immediate neighborship in the string?

Comment: From the sources I've found, 'following' **can** certainly have the narrower definition 'immediately after' but doesn't need to and usually doesn't. The same is true for the intransitive verb 'follow', but I've not found an authority saying the same applies for the transitive verb. Perhaps OED can clarify. What this boils down to is that there is ample scope for ambiguity and lack of clarity, as the US court case (comment below) illustrates. With different senses, both '3 follows 1' and '3 does not follow 1' might both be correct. Using 'immediately follows' etc disambiguates.

Comment: Interestingly, we had a debate over very nearly the same question in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137391/replace-string-containing-newline-in-huge-file) just last month. The OP said (paraphrased) “I want to delete all `C`s that occur after a `B`, but not anywhere else”, and another contributor and I couldn’t agree whether that meant `ABCCCDE` should be changed to `ABCCDE` or `ABDE`. The OP indicated that he wanted `ABCCDE`; i.e., he meant “immediately after”. (But changing `CABDEC` to `CABDE` wasn’t even considered to be an option.)

Comment: [Phil White on Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25016&p=90275#p90275) wisely comments that 'Immediacy does not appear to me to be the crucial issue. Far more, it is the aspect of something being "the next in sequence" within the current discourse context.' So rather than arguing over how dictionary No 438 defines the senses licensed for 'follow', we'd be better looking at the sequence involved in (or deducible from) the context in which it is being used. If the sequence is not obvious, we should use different or enhanced phraseology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Follows" just means "comes after," sometimes also meaning "along the same path as". If you want to say that it comes "right after" the other thing, say "immediately follows".

Of course when there are only two items, these concepts are identical.

And often the distinction isn't relevant. If I'm following you to your home, it doesn't matter if someone briefly gets between us; I can still follow you.

Comment: Your authority for this answer? Sadly, words often have conflicting senses. RHK Webster's has the sense (admittedly low down the list, and for the intransitive sense): follow: v.i.
15. to come next after something else in sequence, order of time, etc.>> I think that this sense is also sometimes intended for the transitive situation,  though ' "Follows" just means "comes after" ' works most of the time.

Comment: My authority for this answer is "native speaker". It may have different uses in other dialects, but this is the usage I have always seen in the American Northeast, over the past (mumble) decades.

Comment: But I'm also a native speaker, as are, one assumes, the compilers of RHK Webster's. And they've done more research than us. Not being familiar with a usage is not very good evidence for claiming it doesn't exist.

Comment: Dictionaries are not an ultimate answer; they unavoidably reflect the biases of the editors, and they generally lag a few decades behind current usage. And I didn't say the usage didn't exist; I said it's not the best usage to assume when you don't know what the other speaker meant or don't know the listener well enough to guess how they will interpret it.  If you want to post a different answer, feel free, but I stand by mine.

Comment: 'And I didn't say the usage didn't exist': in that case, your 'just' is ambiguous and your answer needs adjusting. I agree that dictionaries are not an ultimate answer. However, 'they unavoidably reflect the biases of the editors': if you'd seen how much effort including corpus-based research goes into compiling the OED, always by panels, you'd realise that they're far less biased than individual _native speakers_. '... they generally lag a few decades behind current usage': the OED updates 4 times a year.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: As I said, feel free to write your own answer if you don't like mine. That's how the site works.

Comment: I'm commenting on _your_ answer. The Help Center includes the following guideline:  'Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research ...'. I'm saying that an answer with no authority beyond 'Trust me: I'm a native speaker' should be confined to a comment. I'm still looking for a dictionary which gives the sense 'to come immediately after'; I'd expect an answer to contain comments on such research. OP needs to know if there is an ambiguity here.

Comment: I still can't post what I'd accept as a valid answer. But a [1968 US legal appeal](http://openjurist.org/401/f2d/425/roark-v-l-lewis-w-reese-s) hinged on whether 'following' _must_ mean 'next': The trustees [interpret a clause in the resolution to mean] that 'following' signatory employment means retirement must come 'immediately after' such employment. Appellants contend that that interpretation is an unreasonable one because 'following' means 'after,' but not 'immediately after.' Webster, New International Dictionary 981 (Unabr. ed. 1950) defines 'following' as: '1. Next after ...

Comment: Law and colloquial language are extremely different things. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I won't, because the Webster reference does not indicate that the ambiguity is confined to the legal register or colloquial usage. And I (as I said, also a native speaker) have heard at least 'following' used to mean 'next' rather than the broader 'later in time, a list ...' on occasion. Scott (above) has met the same problem.